# Does std::pair destroy its dynamically allocated objects?

Tags: c++, stl

For example containers like `std::vector<T*>` destroy all of its elements that were addad to it by `push_back(new T)`. Does `std::pair<T1*, T2*>` does the same when you initialize it like `{ new T1, new T }`?

I have this question because `std::pair` is a structure unlike containers that are classes (it does not mean anything but still). I can not find any information about it.

Edited: despite the fact I thought containers `delete` their dynamically allocated elements, this is wrong.

Comment: No it does not. Modern `c++` teaches you to avoid using `new` altogether so you don't have to manually manage memory.

Comment: @drescherjm: First they teach you to avoid `malloc()`, and then comes the turn for `new` :)

Comment: Containers of smart pointers will solve this issue for you.

Comment: _containers like `std::vector<T*>` destroy all of its elements that were addad to it by `push_back(new T)`_ — that's not true (pointers themselves are destoryed but not the objects they are pointing to).

Comment: No. std::vector & std::pair would release the elements, but if those happen to be pointers, the pointed objects would not be automatically deleted. If you want that to happen, use the appropriate smart pointers (unique_ptr, shared_ptr, weak_ptr).

Comment: *I have this question because std::pair is a structure unlike containers that are classes* - if you mean `struct` vs. `class`, the only thing affected by that choice is the default access to members (including under inheritance).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both vector and pair destroy their elements.

Neither vector nor pair destroy or deallocate objects pointed by their elements.

Some examples:

```
{
    std::vector<int> v {42};
}
```

Vector allocated dynamically, and deallocated.

```
{
    std::vector<int*> v {new int};
}
```

Vector allocated dynamically, and deallocated. I allocated dynamically, and leaked the allocation.

```
{
    std::pair<int, int> v {42, 24};
}
```

No dynamic allocation whatsoever. Great.

```
{
    std::pair<int*, int*> v {new int, new int};
}
```

I allocated dynamically twice, and leaked both.

```
{
    std::pair<int*, int*> v {new int, new int};
    delete v.first;
    delete v.second;
}
```

No leak.... but don't do this. Avoid unnecessary dynamic allocation, and don't use owning bare pointers.

Answer (score 11):

No.

`std::vector` does not destroy objects whose pointers were added to it by `push_back(new T)`.

Neither does `std::pair`.